# How can I get Youtube videos after searching through the Youtube api

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

I want to make a python program that uses Youtube's api. The thing that I want to do is searching Youtube videos and showing the results in my program. Program gonna run like this: There is gonna be a textbox you write something and hit enter then you'll see the Youtube results below . What should I do for doing this in python or is this impossible?

Comment: Are you asking for the youtube search algorithm?

Comment: @ksooklall No, I just want to search videos through Youtube api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube has a Data API with very helpful example snippets. I would suggest reading through the official documentation before proceeding.

Relevant section: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Snippet tool instructions: https://google-developers.appspot.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippet_instructions